# Office-js Excel: Get filename of newly saved file

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

How can I get filename of newly saved file?
Normally, I can get the filename using:

```
Office.context.document.url
```

However, when the user opens a new workbook, it doesn't really have a filename, and oddly enough this line of code doesn't work even after they save it.
Instead, they have to save it, close, and then re-open the file for that code to read their filename.

Is there a way to refresh the Office context after a save, or another workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried `Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync([, options], callback);`. From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfilepropertiesasync) I can gather that this should also return the document url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the file path for the given document. [`getFilePropertiesAsync(options, callback)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js#getfilepropertiesasync-options--callback-)

```js
var fileProperties = Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync([, options], callback);
var fileUrl = fileProperties.url;
```

- If you opened from a document library, you'll get the full URL of the document including the file name.
- If you opened the file from your local drive it will give you the full path of the document (including the file name as well)
- If the file has not yet been saved, it will return null.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Nate Radebaugh for pointing out: [`getFilePropertiesAsync(options, callback)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js#getfilepropertiesasync-options--callback-)
That works as expected and is able to provide the filename of a newly saved document.

Since I'm a bigger fan of async/await over callbacks, I thought I'd add this to his answer:

```
async loadFileName() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(null, (res) => {
      if (res && res.value && res.value.url) {
        let name = res.value.url.substr(res.value.url.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        resolve(name);
      }
      resolve('');
    })
  });
}
```

`res.value.url` returns the entire file url/path (C:\Users\username\Desktop\Book1.xlsx) and in my case, since I only want the filename (Book1.xlsx), I trim it off the end.