# From an office add-in, Is it possible to get the location the office document was loaded from?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am wondering if it is possible to get the location a document has been loaded from, from within an office add-in?

I can get the host type and platform type but what I need next is the location

e.g.

- C:\someFolder\myDocument.docx
- \\folder1\folder2\myDocument.docx
- https://mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/DocumentLibrary/myDocument.docx

I can see in the documentation that there is a Interface **Office.FileProperties** that has a property called url. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.fileproperties?view=common-js but I have no idea where to retrieve this value from in the actual add-in code or if it will actually have the value I am after.

Any insight would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions in this previously answered question are likely helpful: [Office-js Excel: Get filename of newly saved file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092038/office-js-excel-get-filename-of-newly-saved-file).

Comment: Thanks @jeremy-msft